# A hierarchy in CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 tables, Categories and Sub Categories. Is it prossible to present all sub categories in a checkbox list arraged by their cagetories?

Something like this:

Category 1

- sub category checkbox1
- sub category checkbox2

Category 2

- sub category checkbox3
- sub category checkbox4

Category 3

- sub category checbox5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [TreeView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx) control, or a nested repeater (for 1 level of subcategories).

Comment: The problem is, I only want the sub categories to be check-able, and not the category headings.